# What is the purpose of the Draught of Living Death?

Tags: lego-harry-potter-years-5-7

Near the beginning of Year 6, the Draught of Living Death is unlocked and becomes available in hub cauldrons. When drunk, it appears to "disguise" your character as a skeleton. (Rather than becoming a skeletal minifig, you become a black minifig with a skeleton painted on it.)

Is there ever a reason to do so? The game has so far offered no explanation as to *why* I'd need to become a skeleton. Or is it purely cosmetic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is purely cosmetic.  There is no point in the game where you need to turn into a pseudo-skeleton.

Answer (score 3):

It is needed to get into the secret room in Dumbledore's observatory. You need it, the skeleton costume and the cursed Dumbledore.