# Draught of Living Death/Astronomy Tower Secret Room

Tags: lego-harry-potter-years-5-7

In this thread: [What is the purpose of the Draught of Living Death?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/39606/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-draught-of-living-death/363706#363706)

someone says that, along with Dumbledore (Cursed) and Skeleton, the Draught of Living Death is needed to gain access to a secret room in Dumbledore's Observatory (I'm assuming this means the Astronomy Tower) but they don't actually say how to do this. The nearest cauldron to the Astronomy Tower is in the lobby, and the D.o.L.D. wears off as soon as you go through the doors into the courtyard. Even then, there seems to be no actionable area in the Astronomy Tower that could open a secret room, other than the grid by the already used Parsletongue puzzle.

Does anyone know anything about this??